# Group sequential data

Tags: php, mysql

It's a bit hard to describe what I intend. So I will just show what I want to achieve and you can tell me if it's possible and how.

This is for a stock transaction log.

DATA:

```
t_type  productid  t_date                t_stock   t_stock_after
1       2          2013-11-06 16:52:30   1         80
1       3          2013-11-06 15:50:40   1         60
1       2          2013-11-06 13:52:30   1         81
1       2          2013-11-06 13:48:30   1         82
1       2          2013-11-05 13:52:30   1         83
1       2          2013-11-04 14:56:30   1         84
1       2          2013-11-04 13:55:30   2         85
1       2          2013-11-04 13:54:30   1         87
2       2          2013-11-04 13:53:30   10        88
1       2          2013-11-04 13:52:30   1         78
```

OBJECTIVE:

```
t_type  productid  t_date       t_stock   t_stock_after
1       2          2013-11-06   3          80
1       2          2013-11-05   1          83
1       2          2013-11-04   4          84
2       2          2013-11-04   10         88
1       2          2013-11-04   1          78
```

So what I wish to do is group the * (asterisk) ones only because they share the same day and type and they are sequential.

```
     t_type  productid  t_date                t_stock   t_stock_after
*    1      2          2013-11-06 16:52:30   1         80
*    1      2          2013-11-06 13:52:30   1         81
*    1      2          2013-11-06 13:48:30   1         82
     1      2          2013-11-05 13:52:30   1         83
*    1      2          2013-11-04 14:56:30   1         84
*    1      2          2013-11-04 13:55:30   2         85
*    1      2          2013-11-04 13:54:30   1         87
     2      2          2013-11-04 13:53:30   10        88
     1      2          2013-11-04 13:52:30   1         78
```

**UPDATE:**

I also realized something, t_stock_after does not SUM. It only shows the last t_stock_after.
Sample data has been corrected to simulate real life data and help get to an answer.

In order to help as much as possible:

This is the table:

id (int and auto increment), productid, userid, t_type, t_date, t_stock, t_stock_after, t_reason

**UPDATE 2 - WORKING CODE**

And as I said, here is the code I eventually managed to create =)

SQL:

```
if(isset($_GET['mindate']) && $_GET['mindate']!="" && isset($_GET['maxdate']) && $_GET['maxdate']!="")
  $stocklog = $dataserver->query("SELECT t_type, productid, t_date, SUM(t_stock) AS stock, SUM(t_stock_after) AS stockafter FROM store_log_transactions WHERE productid = ".$_GET['id']." AND (DATE(t_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB('".$_GET['mindate']."', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND '".$_GET['maxdate']."') GROUP BY t_date, t_type");
else
  $stocklog = $dataserver->query("SELECT t_type, productid, t_date, SUM(t_stock) AS stock, SUM(t_stock_after) AS stockafter FROM store_log_transactions WHERE productid = ".$_GET['id']." AND (t_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()) GROUP BY t_date, t_type");
```

PHP:

```
$id=1;
$temp_date = "";
$temp_type="";
$temp_stock=0;
$temp_stock_after=9999999999;
while($log = $stocklog->fetch_object())
{
$current_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($log->t_date));
$current_type = $log->t_type;
    $current_stock = $log->stock;
    $current_after = $log->stockafter;

    if($current_date==$temp_date || $id==1)
    {
        if($current_type==$temp_type || $id==1)
        {
            $temp_stock+=$current_stock;
            if($temp_stock_after>$current_after);
                $temp_stock_after=$current_after;
            $temp_date=$current_date;
            $temp_type=$current_type;
        }
        else
        {
            $transactiontype;
            switch($temp_type)
            {
                case 1: $transactiontype='net sales'; break;
                case 2: $transactiontype='net return'; break;
                case 3: $transactiontype='transfer in'; break;
                case 4: $transactiontype='trasnfer out'; break;
            }
            echo '<div class="listitem"><div>'.$temp_stock.'</div><div>'.$temp_stock_after.'</div><div>'.$transactiontype.'</div><div>'.$temp_date.'</div></div>';
            $temp_date=$current_date;
            $temp_type=$current_type;
            $temp_stock_after=$current_after;
            $temp_stock=$current_stock;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $transactiontype;
        switch($temp_type)
        {
            case 1: $transactiontype='net sales'; break;
            case 2: $transactiontype='net return'; break;
            case 3: $transactiontype='transfer in'; break;
            case 4: $transactiontype='trasnfer out'; break;
        }
        echo '<div class="listitem"><div>'.$temp_stock.'</div><div>'.$temp_stock_after.'</div><div>'.$transactiontype.'</div><div>'.$temp_date.'</div></div>';
        $temp_date=$current_date;
        $temp_type=$current_type;
        $temp_stock_after=$current_after;
        $temp_stock=$current_stock;
    }
    $id++;
    if($id>$stocklog->num_rows) {
        $transactiontype;
        switch($temp_type)
        {
            case 1: $transactiontype='net sales'; break;
            case 2: $transactiontype='net return'; break;
            case 3: $transactiontype='transfer in'; break;
            case 4: $transactiontype='trasnfer out'; break;
        }
        echo '<div class="listitem"><div>'.$temp_stock.'</div><div>'.$temp_stock_after.'</div><div>'.$transactiontype.'</div><div>'.$temp_date.'</div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: PRIMARY KEY. It appears to be the missing column `id`, but just wanted to make sure

Comment: I does have a primary key named id. See update ;)

Comment: Well, in just 30 minutes I made it work exactly as I wanted to, using PHP. I'll post how I did it tomorrow. Thank you all for your time, and my apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this ...

`GROUP BY t_type, productid, DATE(t_date)`

Comment: Almost. That is also grouping the last record which I don't want to.

Comment: @FábioAlves whats the reasoning behind not wanting the last row grouped with its other like entries ?

Comment: In this case it's the last row, because that's the last entry.
The rows marked with * should appear condensed. If I group the last row with the others then it will not make sense as a log. I want to see the summary of all stock transactions in order so that I know want happened to stock.

Sold 1 unit, now have 78; 
Received 10 units now have 88; 
Sold 4 units now have 84; 
Sold 1 units now have 83 (different day); 
Sold 3 units now have 80 (different day);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are going to want to group the dates by only date, and each other field by itself, then sum the t_stock_after.  If that is correct this would be pretty easy and would be

```
SELECT t_type, procuctid, DATE(t_date) as t_date, t_stock, SUM(t_stock_after) as t_stock_after
FROM table
GROUP BY t_type, product_id, DATE(t_date);
```

Comment: Sorry same result as Christopher Morrissey. It still groups all day 4 t_type 1 rows. The last one can't be grouped since it's not sequential with the others.

I know this may be difficult to accomplish only in MYSQL so I accept PHP to help achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

So whatever else you want, *first off*, you want the rows returned by this query, right?...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM stock_transaction_log a
         JOIN stock_transaction_log b  
           ON b.id <= a.id
        GROUP
           BY id
     ) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT a.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM stock_transaction_log a
         JOIN stock_transaction_log b  
           ON b.id <= a.id
        GROUP
           BY id
     ) y 
    ON y.t_type = x.t_type 
   AND y.productid = x.productid 
   AND DATE(y.t_date) = DATE(x.t_date) 
   AND y.rank = x.rank - 1 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

Edited to allow for the possibility that `id` is not an unbroken sequence.

Comment: That returns every single row.

Comment: Awesome! Made a small change in "AND y.rank = x.rank + 1". The only thing missing now is just the stock count of t_stock. Other than that it's fantastic.

Comment: !?! But that appears to be a different intermediate result from what you've shown above !?! It would be really useful to see your id column.

Comment: Hmm... although it works with the sample data I provided, it doesn't work if different products are in between. I'll update the post to reflect more case scenarios, in the mean time, I'll be using the code provided by all of you and try to make it work using PHP. If I do get to work exactly like I want it, I'll post the solution. Fingers crossed.

Comment: bogascorp.com/public/img1.jpg; bogascorp.com/public/img2.jpg; Here are the two images with data and sql

Comment: Images? That's not how we roll. This query joins on productid - so that couldn't make any difference - unless id IS NOT your PRIMARY KEY but merely a component of it.

Comment: id IS primary key with auto increment.